# I have to "fudge" a change in /etc/exports in order to get mount -a to execute, what's the issue?

Tags: nfs, mount

Whenever I have to reboot server1, the only way I can get NFS mounts back up on server2 is to change one of the "fsid" integers in the **/etc/exports** file on server1.  Otherwise, the **mount -a** command just hangs on server2.

**Typical Scenario:**

Server1 is rebooted. On server1, I have two lines of code in **/etc/exports**:

```
/mnt/ramdisk/dir1 *(fsid=0,rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,async)
/mnt/ramdisk/dir2 *(fsid=1,rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,async)
```

I issue this command:

```
"exportfs -r".
```

On server2, I have this in **/etc/fstab:**

```
xxx.xxx.x.x:/server1_dir1/ /dir1_server2 nfs async,noatime 0 0
xxx.xxx.x.x:/server2_dir2  /dir2_server2 nfs async,noatime 0 0
```

I first "umount" the old dirs that now have stale NFS handles. Then,

```
"mount -a"
```

The command hangs.  After I kill it, **df** shows dir1 mounted, but dir2 did not.

The only way to get both dirs to mount is to change the fsid integer to something else. For example, on server1 we now have:

```
/mnt/ramdisk/dir1 *(fsid=0,rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,async)
/mnt/ramdisk/dir2 *(fsid=2,rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,async)
```

I changed **fsid=1 to =2**. I again issue the **exportfs -r** command, and voila, the **mount -a** command works on server2.

Perhaps I do not understand what **fsid** really does, but obviously there must be a better way to "remount" NFS than having to randomly edit the fsid number every time?

**EDIT**: If I do not have **fsid** included in my exports file on server1, it gives me

```
"Warning: /mnt/ramdisk/dir1 requires fsid= for NFS export"
```

And, if I set fsid=0 for both lines (dir1 and dir2), then the mount points end up being the same as all my files were being copied to the dir1 location! So it seems the only way for this to work is to constantly switch fsid integers, somewhat randomly.

**EDIT2**: I removed **fsid=0** since it is "special", and changed them to **fsid=1** and **fsid=2** in **/etc/exports** on server1.  This of course worked (since file was changed). But today just had to reboot forcibly, and after (slowly) unmounting the stale drives from server2, **mount -a** failed, as before. So, (as before), I edited the exports file on server1, this time, **fsid=2** and **fsid=3**, **exportfs -r**, and voila, **mount -a** works again on server2.  Back to square 1.

**EDIT3** Critical info:  If I take everything down in a controlled manner (i.e...server1 does not "crash"), and first unmount the dirs on server2, then reboot server1, THEN mount -a on server2, it works great.  It's only when the mounts on server2 are abruptly cut off that this problem occurs.  So I"m guessing something needs to be reset on server2? I know it takes a long time to unmount the stale handles on server2 after server1 crashes.

Comment: Why are you specifying `fsid=` in the first place, and are these directories not both on the same FS (`/mnt/ramdisk`)?

Comment: If I do not specify fsid=, then when I exportfs it says:
"Warning: /mnt/ramdisk/dir1 requires fsid= for NFS export"  (same warning for dir2 as well). I used to have them both fsid=0, but I have been randomly changing the values in order to get it to mount on other machine.

Comment: ALSO, if I set fsid=0 for both dir1 and dir2, then they end up being the same mount point apparently!

Comment: `fsid=0` has a special meaning; you generally should not be using it, and certainly not in this scenario.

Comment: @MichaelHampton please re-post your comment as a proper answer, preferably with an explanation.

Comment: False alarm. I had to reboot sever1, and even with fsid=1 and fside=2, "mount -a" failed on server2.  So, I had to edit /etc/exports again, and this time I did fsid=2 and fsid=3, exported it, and voila, now "mount -a" works on server2.  So I'm back to square 1.

Comment: Any ideas on this? I found out that the mount only fails if server1 is taken down BEFORE I can unmount the dirs on server2. So the abrupt disonnection is what's causing remount to hang, and only way to fix is to keep changing the fsid integers on server1.

Answer (score 5):

My guess would be that the problem is caused by the use of `fsid=0` in one of your exports.

Remember that the `fsid` is meant to uniquely identify devices when the underlying filesystem driver doesn't provide its own unique IDs. And in particular, `fsid=0` has a [special meaning](http://linux.die.net/man/5/exports):

> For NFSv4, there is a distinguished filesystem which is the root of all exported filesystem. This is specified with `fsid=root` or `fsid=0` both of which mean exactly the same thing.

Since this clearly isn't what you want, always use an fsid other than 0.

Comment: I changed them to fsid=1 and fsid=2.  It worked the first time, but then I had to reboot server1, which messed up the nfs mounts on server2. After some time, I was finally able to umount dir1 and dir2 from server2. Now that server1 is up, I did "mount -a" on server2, but timed out. I had to "fudge", again, fsid=2 and fsid=3 this time (since it was already 1 and 2).